# GraphView cannot resolve symbol addSeries()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-graphview

I'm trying to use Graphview following [this tutorial](http://www.android-graphview.org/documentation/how-to-create-a-simple-graph).

But I have some issue with `GraphView.addSeries()` that cannot be resolve.

So here is my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.florian.graph2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
    //compile 'com.jjoe:graphview:4.0.1'
}
```

I've tried both using the Maven Central Repository with the line `compile 'com.jjoe:graphview:4.0.1'`, and Download and paste the jar file with the line `compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')`.

I don't know why but the first didn't work at all and with the second one in the line `graph.addSeries(series);` addSeries cannot be resolve.

**My code is Here**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{
            new DataPoint(0,1),
            new DataPoint(1,0),
            new DataPoint(2,5),
            new DataPoint(3,2),
            new DataPoint(4,7)
    });

    graph.addSeries(series);
}
```

If you guys have any idea it will be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the same case, I put everything in onCreate method and now it's working.

Answer (score -1):

Search for dependencies, add libraries, then you can import the classes:

[image]

Comment: Since links can be broken, please provide code as a sample when possible.